# Why is ChangeListener triggered only twice?

Tags: javafx, event-listener

I am trying to create an animation of a circle that translates horizontally and crosses a vertical line which is in the middle. I add an event listener which prints true whenever the circle's centre is near the line.

```
        Circle circle = new Circle(100, 400, 100);
        Line line = new Line(400, 0, 400, 800);
        BooleanBinding pos = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                return circle.translateXProperty().getValue() >= 297 && circle.translateXProperty().getValue() <= 303;
            }
        }, circle.translateXProperty());
        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition();
        translate.setByX(600);
        translate.setDuration(Duration.millis(3000));
        translate.setCycleCount(10);
        translate.setAutoReverse(true);
        translate.setNode(circle);
        pos.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean t1) {
                if(t1) {
                    System.out.println(pos.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
        translate.play();
```

However, the event listener is triggered only twice i.e. I see only two true values printed in the console. It seems the event listener stops working after some time as decreasing the duration of transition increases the number of trues printed but it stops working after some time. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: The binding is probably getting garbage collected, as it internally registers weak listeners with the translate property. Try making the binding an instance variable.

Comment: @James_D Yes, that fixed it. Maybe make it an answer? Also, could you tell more about why that happened?